# Proving Bijectivity and Finding the inverse of a function.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I am given this problem:

Suppose a, b, c, d ∈ R and ad − bc ≠ 0. Deﬁne f : R\ {$d\over -c$} → R\ {$a \over c$} by f(x) is $ax+b \over cx+d$.

How do I prove that it is injective and surjective?

Next, how do I get the formula for its inverse?

For injective, I say that we assume $f(x_1)$ = $f(x_2)$, so, $ax_1+b \over cx_1+d$ = $ax_2+b \over cx_2+d$, which means $x_1$ = $x_2$, so it is injective.

I do not know what to say about surjective. Can I say something like let y be in R\ {$a \over c$}. Then y = $ax+b \over cx+d$, and $f(x) = y$?

For the inverse, is the result $a d-b\over x-a c$?

I can use all the help I can get. The injective and surjective stuff gets to be pretty confusing for me.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: To memorize the meaning of injective and surjective, I use the idea that injective means "at most one origin" and surjective means "at least one origin". Now bijective is the combination of the two which implies "exactly one origin". HTH

Answer (score 0):

To prove surjectivity, write
$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=y$$
and solve for $x$. Use the fact that $y\neq a/c$

Note that when you solve for $x$ you obtain a formula for $x$, given $y$. This is exactly the inverse function.

Comment: And why can't y equal a/c?

Comment: @J-Play That's what you wrote yourself: $f:R\backslash \{\frac{d}{c}\} \rightarrow R\backslash \{\frac{a}{c}\}$

Comment: @J-Play That's how **you** defined the function $\;f\;$ !

Comment: Oh yeah! Duh! Sorry.

Comment: So for solving for x, I get as x = $-b \over a-y(c+d)$ Is that correct?

Comment: $y = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}$ means $y(cx + d) = ax + b$, thus $ycx - ax = b - yd$. Because $y \neq a/c$ this means that $x = \frac{b - yd}{yc - a}$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, it's been a long day for me. How do we show that solving for x makes it surjective?